# Is there a way to ad dynamic shortcodes to upload image URL from Pods or ACF with Gutenberg image block?

Tags: dynamic, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to ad dynamic display or images via "upload url", is this even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is 5 months old and I expect the OP no longer needs the answer but...

For anyone else finding it, you can't add a dynamic image from a custom field with the standard Gutenberg image block. But you can if you add the free version of the GenerateBlocks plugin that includes an image block that works with dynamic content from custom fields.

Comment: Just read this, I'll give this a shot, I use Generate Press premium, so this should work, thanks!